# Why I get Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use node/express with mysql database. So at registration controller I have:

```
import {db} from "../db.js"
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs"
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"

export const register = (req, res)=>{
         const q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?"
        db.query(q, [req.body.email], (err, data)=>{
            if(err) {
              console.log(err)
              return res.status(500).json(err)
            }
            
            if(data.length) return res.status(409).json("user already exsits")
        } )
        //CREATE A NEW USER
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt)
        const qr = "INSERT INTO user ( `username`, `email`, `password` ) VALUES (?)"
        const username = req.body.username
        const password = hashedPassword
        const email = req.body.email
        console.log( "username, email, password", username, email, password)
        const user = [username, email, password]
        db.query(qr, [user], (err, data)=>{
            if(err) {
                console.log('error insertion', err)
                return res.status(500).json(err)
            }
            
           return res.status(200).json("user is created!")
        } ) 

 }
```

It works fine for the first instance of user registration, however, when I post the same user json data again, I get this error and the app crashes:

```
$ nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
request received
API is listening on port 8080
username, email, password test test@me.com 

    $2a$10$NJ0/NfzsMY3cBBcyjdnY7..1NYlta5FTQI.qa25x2dh56R3blnqYm
    /home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
          throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
          ^
    
    Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
        at Query.<anonymous> (file:///home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/controllers/auth.js:42:35)
        at Query.<anonymous> (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
        at Query._callback (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
        at Sequence.end (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
        at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/me/react-projects/catapp/back/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8) {
      code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
    }
    
    Node.js v18.13.0
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm wondering what causes this how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in the branch where you return the `409` error, all the code after that block still runs anyway. So if an email was already in the system, you are first sending the `409` error, then you still attempt to create the user and finally you are returning another http status code (200).

Calling `return` inside your callbacks only ends the inner function, not the outer one.

You need to refactor your code to deal with this. Either by nesting all your code inside your callbacks for each query, or learn about async/await and promises so you can write your code in a way that's a bit more natural.

I'd strongly recommend you stop using callbacks for these cases and switch to promises.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I realized that I needed to move `//CREATE A NEW USER` into the `db.query` callback.

Comment: Yes, and that's not the only problem. It's the quick solution to your problem though. good luck

Comment: How do you rewrite this code in a more robust way then? I was following this tutorial, and I suppose the guy is quite proficient in React/Node stuff:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EuNnZEp2sQ

Comment: I can't speak for the video, but modern code uses promises and async/await. Not callbacks.